# Eigenvelues of $f_A:V\to V, X\to AXA.$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a vector space on $\mathbb C$ made by $2\times 2$ complex matrix.

And for $M\in V,$ define $f_M : V\to V$ by $X\mapsto MXM.$

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ **real** and **symmetric** matrix that has two eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu \ (\lambda \neq \mu)$.

Then, calculate the eigenvalues of $f_A$.

---

Since $A$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$, there exist $u,v\in \mathbb{C^2}$ s.t. $Au=\lambda u, Av=\mu v.$

And in order to calculate the eigenvalues of $f_A$, I have to consider $f_A(X)=\nu X.$

I tried letting $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}, X=\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix}$ and calculating $AXA=\nu X$, but this is too complicated so that I couldn't.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you see why you only need to consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\&\mu\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @user10354138 I can't see… .  Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $A = UDU^T$, where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu\end{pmatrix}$.

Note that:
$$
f_A(X) = UDU^TXUDU^T = Uf_D(U^TXU)U^T.
$$
If we denote by $\sigma_U$ the linear map on $V$ given by $Y\mapsto UYU^T$ we have
$$
f_A = \sigma_U \circ f_D \circ \sigma_U^{-1}.
$$
This shows $f_A$ and $f_D$ are similar operators on $V$ and hence they have the same eigenvalues.

Now consider usual the basis $\{E_{i,j}\}$ for $V$, where $E_{i,j}$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ component and zero elsewhere. A bit of algebra gives
\begin{align}
f_D(E_{1,1}) & = \lambda^2 E_{1,1} \\ 
f_D(E_{1,2}) & = \lambda\mu E_{1,2} \\ 
f_D(E_{2,1}) & = \lambda\mu E_{2,1} \\ 
f_D(E_{2,2}) & = \mu^2 E_{2,2}.
\end{align}

So there are three eigenvalues: $\lambda^2$, $\mu^2$, and $\lambda\mu$. Interestingly enough, note that
\begin{align}
\det(f_A) & = \det(A)^3 \\ 
\text{Tr}(f_A) & = \text{Tr}(A)^2 - \det(A).
\end{align}

Comment: This is a elegant solution, but how did you come up with that idea ? @Pirate_Prentice

Comment: $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, so by the spectral theorem we can decompose it as $A = UDU^T$. The "philosophy" here is that $A$ and $D$ are, up to an orthogonal change of coordinates, the same. So if we can answer the question for $D$ we'll also have an answer for $A$. Finding the eigenvalues of $f_D$ is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.